# Let $G = (V, E)$ be a hamiltonian graph. Show that the $diam (G) \le {|V| \over 2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a hamiltonian graph. Show that the $diam (G) \le {|V| \over 2}$.

I have a concrete idea to proof this, but I think it lacks a bit of formalism.

Let's assume the opposite, so

$$diam(G) > {|V| \over 2}, $$

which is equivalent to

$$diam(G) \ge {|V| \over 2} + 1.$$

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $|V| = n$ and that the hamiltonian cycle looks like this:

$$(v_1, \ ... \, v_{n \over 2}, v_{{n \over 2}+1}, v_{{n \over 2}+2} \ ... \  v_n, v_{n+1}), v_{n+1} = v_1.$$

Now, the diameter is defined as the longest distance between two vertices $v_i, v_j$, and the distance is defined as the shortest path between those two edges. But $diam(G) \ge {n \over 2} + 1 = d(v_1, v_{{n \over 2}+2})$ implies that there wouldn't be a shorter path between $v_1$ and $v_{{n \over 2}+2}$, but considering the fact that we can rewrite the hamiltonian cycle like this:

$$(v_{n+1}, v_n, \ ... \, v_{{n \over 2}+2}, v_{{n \over 2}+1}, v_{{n \over 2}}, \ ... \  v_1),$$

and since $v_{n+1} = v_1$, it should become clear that

$$d(v_{n+1}, v_{{n \over 2}+2}) < d(v_1, v_{{n \over 2}+2}),$$

which means that we found a shorter path, contradicting the statement from above. So, the general idea is to just walk the hamiltonian cycle backwards.

Comment: You claim the wrong thing, while the idea is true

Comment: $\mathrm{diam}(G)>|V|/2$ does *not* imply $\mathrm{diam}(G)\ge|V|/2+1$ when $|V|$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core idea is right. I would avoid using proof by contradiction. There you made a small mistake which I hinted to in the comments.

Let it write me down with less reference to conrete vertices:

Take two vertices $v,w\in V(G)$ and let $C$ be a hamiltonian cycle of $G$. $C$ has length $n:=|V|$. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the two arcs of $C$ between $v$ and $w$. We know that $|P_1|+|P_2|=|C|=n$, and therefore (pidgeonhole principle) one of the paths is of length at most $n/2$. Hence $d(v,w)\leq n/2$. This holds for all pairs of vertices, thus $\mathrm{diam}(G)\le n/2$.

Comment: Beautiful, short proof, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is **right**.

Assume, $v_i$ and $v_j$ are those two vertices, defining the diameter $d \triangleq diam(G)$. Since graph $G$ is Hamiltonian, take this Hamiltonian cycle. WLOG, assume also indexing of vertices is their order on the path. There are at least two possible paths between $v_i$ and $v_j$, namely walking along Hamiltonian cycle forward, i.e. $(v_i, v_{i+1}, \ldots, v_j)$, and walking backward $(v_i, v_{i-1}, \ldots, v_{j+1}, v_j)$. Sum of lengths of those two paths is exactly $n$, but each one is at least as long as the **shortest** path between $v_i$ and $v_j$, hence the sum is at least $2d > n$.

Contradiction.